# After Upgrading to 22.04 (Inconsistently) Cannot Manually Resize Some Windows The Whole Way To Screen Bottom: Without A Gap

Tags: 22.04, window, resize

Since Upgrading to 22.04, I've noticed an annoying problem which is that, when resizing windows manually, by dragging the lower-right corner, sometimes (not always) it is impossible to enlarge the window entirely to the edge of the screen; there is always a gap of a few pixels. The width of the gap varies, and sometimes there is no gap. Sometimes there will be a gap on the right, but not at the bottom, or vice versa, and in general the gap has an unequal size. I have not figured out what causes the gap, but it does not seem to depend on the program being used. It may depend on the absolute position of the window and may be a question of the resizing rounding to a fixed multiple of pixels, but I haven't tested this.

It is very annoying, because when it leaves a gap, I then cannot bring the window to focus later by clicking on the edge of the screen.

Normally, the way I layer my windows is that I leave certain ones on the edge of the screen, including right or bottom borders, so that I can later easily bring them into focus by clicking on the edge of the screen, which is easy to do quickly. With a gap, it becomes much more tedious and time-consuming to click on these windows because I have to carefully aim the cursor as not to overshoot.

As a workaround I have been able to move the window to the edge of the screen, and then resize it as desired. However this is annoying, and I would like to restore the old functionality where manually resizing would easily and exactly match the size of the window to the edge of the screen.

How can I bring back the old, desired behavior, in which dragging a window under resizing, to the edge or corner of the screen, will exactly size it to the border of the screen, with no gap?